# Django AssertionError: 404 != 200

Tags: python, django, listview, testing, http-status-code-404

I have a Class based view:

```
class PromocionListView(ListView):
    model = Promocion
```

and this url path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('promocion/list', PromocionListView.as_view(), name='promocion_list')]
```

so i made the following test:

```
class PromocionTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.promocion = Promocion.objects.create(fecha_de_inicio = date(2022,7,6),duracion = 90)

    def test_url_exists_at_correct_location(self):
        response = self.client.get('promocion/list')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

but it is showing the error: AssertionError: 404 != 200.
Does anything knows why this is happening? I googled it a lot but I couldn't find an answer

Comment: Does adding a slash at the start of the url fix the issue? - `self.client.get('/promocion/list')`

Comment: I already did it. But still doesn't work. Thanks for your comment